# Magento 1.9 Database transfer

Tags: magento-1.9, database, best-practice

We are trying to create our product with a clean version of Magento. But we need to transfer our database. Based on our research we have a couple of choices.

1. Transfer important tables as Mysql dump.
2. Transfer with pre-made modules
3. Transfer the whole database and then clean data in the new version.

Anyone who has the similar experience, please consult me to a best practice

Comment: i would also recommend you to use third-party tool, as i think it is the most safe way to transfer data. i used [Store Manager](https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/how-to/how-to-transfer-magento-data-from-one-store-to-another/) to export products, categories, customers, orders and attributes to the new store. there's also the Trial version of it, so you can make it for free within two weeks

Answer (score -1):

I think that the second solution are the best you can try to use an export and import of data